# How do I change permissions on rolling python log files without calling os.chmod over and over?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I'm working with the Python logging configuration below

```
import logging
import os

#Setup logging
logger = logging.getLogger('/logs/some-log')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler = RotatingFileHandler('./logs/some-log.log', maxBytes=10240, backupCount=5)
logger.addHandler(handler)
#End Logging

#Set Logging Permissions
os.chmod('/logs/some*.log', 0o755)
#End Set Logging Permissions
```

I have a rolling log of 5 files. Let's say this program kicks off for the first time and there is just one log file. It's fine. The permissions are set at the start of the application.

However, this code is at the beginning of an application that's started once a month. I don't think some-log1.log, some-log2.log, some-log3.log etc will have their permissions set correctly when they are generated because the chmod command only runs at the start of the application.

I don't want to put the chmod command in my main program loop because it will run every 30 seconds. I also don't want to make some other timer just for this one command which would cause me to maybe have access to the new file depending on when it's generated.

Is there a way to set permissions to the log file in the python logging library? Is there a better way to code this?

Comment: Have you considered using `umask` before running the application?